# Will Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clear all other background Apps in Anroid?

Tags: android, android-intent

I use Code A to start an activity with the Flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, will all other background Apps such as Message, Gmail,Google Map be cleared and released?

**Code A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ui.UIHome.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Read carefully [**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Comment: SImple answer No it won't

Answer (score 1):

No, those are other tasks. Clear top will only have influence within your own task